# Magento API Documentation

Tags: api

Where can I found a Magento API documentation that list all Magento technical functions? I found this link http://docs.magentocommerce.com, however this documentation is not complete and not very detail. For instance, I could not find this function Mage::getModel(String) from this Magento docs.

The documentation I am looking for that something like Java API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/, specified the function description, return type, parameters, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento not provide this type of document because it Magento Use Zend Framwork and which is developed in PHP and PHP is not a strict Language as JAVA.

So you can define your new classes and Methods in your way.

If you are using core classes of magento then  if you want to see which methods This class contain then you can use below PHP Function

```
array get_class_methods ( mixed $class_name )
```

This function will return the method list in array format you can see that use this method

Example

```
<?php

class myclass {
    // constructor
    function myclass()
    {
        return(true);
    }
    // method 1
    function myfunc1()
    {
        return(true);
    }
    // method 2
    function myfunc2()
    {
        return(true);
    }
}
$class_methods = get_class_methods('myclass');
// or
$class_methods = get_class_methods(new myclass());
foreach ($class_methods as $method_name) 
{
    echo "$method_name\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
myclass
myfunc1
myfunc2
```

Comment: Appreciate Keyul. If this is the case, then no choice for me have to this temporary utility class. Cheers.

Comment: @Leongelis You welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found is at: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/ which details out the core Magento classes, and tells a bit about them.  It has helped me in some cases.

I also suggest using Magicento if you are developing for Magento, http://magicento.com/, it is a great tool.  Although it isn't straight up documentation, it helps tremendously in detailing what class functions are available to you as you write your code.

Creating your own classes as Keyul suggested is also a viable option, but if the functionality already exists in the core functions, why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Hi Vallier, big thanks for the links. However, does magicento extension can be installed in eclipse IDE? Or only explicitly for PHPstorm?

Comment: It is a PHPStorm plugin, I didn't really think about what IDE you may be using.  I've only ever developed for Magento in PHPStorm so I didn't think about that.